# Keycloak cluster standalone-ha issue data users

Tags: keycloak

I have a cluster with 2 servers that are in HA, there is some configuration so that when I make a change for example in the password of a user or change of role, etc. the change is made immediately on the 2 servers?

The problem is that a user's password is changed and it does not update on the other server immediately, the same happens when a user is assigned a role mapping, it never updates on both servers, only when the server is reboot

OS: Linux (ubuntu 16.04)
keycloak version: 11.0

Thanks for the help

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the first paragraph of your question whether Keycloak has ever propagated the changes to the other servers or not.

Does the setup you use *usually* propagate changes?

If not it sounds like there are issues with your cluster setup.
Do the nodes discover each other? You can check the logs on startup, there is a good illustration on the [Keycloak blog](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/05/keycloak-cluster-setup) on how to check this.

In general it would be a good idea to look over the recommended clustering setup in the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#recommended-network-architecture).
You could [change number of owners](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#cache-configuration) in the cluster, that way both nodes own the data before it is put in the database. Might help if the issue is that the changes are not immediate enough.